# Grails 3 script or command with domain classes

Tags: grails, scripting, command

All I want is a simple script to update some db tables. 
My first try was with create-script. These scripts seem not be able to load domain classes. Then I found people saying, you have to create a command. 
But in order to create a command you need to create a plugin.
This seems not very straight forward to a have a simple dbupdate script.

Can somebody enlighten me on this.

Thanks
Torsten

Comment: as a side note: why not use db migration grails already has on board?

Comment: Its not an migration. I Have to update data I get via XML

Answer (score 0):

Alright! Looks like it is more related to how perform certain db related operations which are not straight forward db-migrations.

Though there could be enormous choices around it, I would like to discuss what could commonly  be used:

1. **Groovy Shell:** You could create a straight forward groovy shell for your grails project and there run a script you created. No matter it is for some data update  or some migration or just a report etc. 
   The basic idea is to have a command line available to run scripts that perform certain task. [This](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/shell.html) link should help more.
2. **DBMigration:** Though in comment you already said it's not a dbmigration,I think your definition of dbmigration is restricted to schema related operations only. That's not true! DBmigration includes `schema + CRUD(including a complicated version with join etc as well)`. We don't prefer crud operations as part of dbmigration as it could be achieved during bootstrap time or using a service method or even some external query or tool.
3. Like you perform any operation using your application, you could perform this action too. Suppose, you have to perform some updates and inserts in a table. Simply create a service and a controller which access this service to perform desired results. I know this makes least sense, but overall idea is to have  a code which could perform desired action.

Well! I would suggest go ahead with first option and create a new shell project pointing to same database. Perform the action there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Right know I did what you suggested in 3., I just thought there should be a simple way to do this in grails, since I want to reuse some Application Logic. The Idea was to a have a cronjob starting that script.